# Import nastran nodes deck in Python using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, nastran

If I want to import a Nastran Deck into a Python Array, in one fell swoop using numpy. How can I go about it? Where am I going wrong?

I have a file with only Grids in it. Grids are all equally spaced with Nastran's Short translator (8 characters)

```
$ MH Nodes
$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678
GRID     25601          58.50002-57.749923.05                      
GRID     25602          58.81002-57.749923.05
```

using the dtype command from Numpy, is great if I understand it correctly. Here is my code:

```
fileMH = "Gnodes.bdf"

dtyp = np.dtype([
                ("Grid",(np.void,8)),
                ("GN",(np.int,8)),
                ("Prop",(np.void,8)),
                ("X",(np.float,8)),
                ("Y",(np.float,8)),
                ("Z",(np.float,8)),
])

f = np.loadtxt(fileMH,dtyp,comments="$")
```

The error I get is a float error, however I was expecting dtype to extract 8 characters at a time out of the string. Here is the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 58.50002-57.749923.05
```

Help is appreciated.

P.S. Can some please make a nastran tag, huge amounts of data crunching is done in nastran, that requires smart programing. It would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dtype` specifies the layout of the binary data in memory.  It doesn't define the format of text in a file.

Your data file has fixed-width fields.  That is, each field uses eight characters, and there is no special delimiter character to separate the fields.  You can read such a file using [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), by specifying the field widths in the `delimiter` argument.

Here's an example in an ipython session.  First, here's your sample file.  (I edited the file to ensure that there are three spaces after the final `05` in the second and third lines, but this wasn't necessary.)

```
In [15]: !cat nastran_data.txt
$ MH Nodes
$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678
GRID     25601          58.50002-57.749923.05   
GRID     25602          58.81002-57.749923.05
```

Here's the data type of the array to be created by `genfromtxt`.  Note that the `GN` field has type `np.int64`, and the `X`, `Y` and `Z` fields have type `np.float64`.

```
In [16]: dt = np.dtype([('Grid', 'S8'), ('GN', np.int64), ('Prop', 'S8'), ('X', np.float64), ('Y', np.float64), ('Z', np.float64)])
```

Read the file using `genfromtxt`, with six fixed-width fields, each of length 8:

```
In [18]: a = np.genfromtxt('nastran_data.txt', dtype=dt, delimiter=(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), skip_header=2)

In [19]: a
Out[19]: 
array([('GRID    ', 25601, '        ', 58.50002, -57.7499, 23.05),
       ('GRID    ', 25602, '        ', 58.81002, -57.7499, 23.05)], 
      dtype=[('Grid', 'S8'), ('GN', '<i8'), ('Prop', 'S8'), ('X', '<f8'), ('Y', '<f8'), ('Z', '<f8')])

In [20]: a['GN']
Out[20]: array([25601, 25602])

In [21]: a['X']
Out[21]: array([ 58.50002,  58.81002])
```

Comment: That's Excellent thank you.... out of curiosity,  how is referencing the binary data in memory helpful?

Answer (score 2):

instead of numpy, perhaps pyNastran would work? https://github.com/SteveDoyle2/pyNastran

this examples prints nodes

```
import pyNastran
from pyNastran.bdf.bdf import BDF
model = BDF()
model.read_bdf('inputdeck.bdf', xref=True)
model.nodes
{1: GRID           1              8.      3.      0.,
 2: GRID           2              8.      9.      0.,
 3: GRID           3              8.     11.      0.,
 4: GRID           4              8.     13.      0.,
 5: GRID           5             -8.      3.      0.,
 6: GRID           6             -8.      9.      0.,
 7: GRID           7             -8.     11.      0.,
 8: GRID           8             -8.     13.      0.,
 9: GRID           9              2.      5.      0.}
```